# A module similar to Innovation News Module for Drupal7?

Tags: 7

Hello I am looking for a module similar to Innovation News so that news content can be developed collaboratively, placed into editions, and exported as XML documents.

It seems Innovation News is on a dead line.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily replace this module by a bunch of other module and that maybe the reason why the module is not anymore maintained. I will try to give you some clues to archive your goal, but maybe you need code a bit.

- [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) - Flag allows you to associate content to an edition.
- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) - Flag work with views, that allows you create views for each edition
- [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) - With Views and VBO you can easily create control panel for each edition.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I need to try. I am currently working with References module which assign a reference field to a content-type but I still can't have the content type Issue displays the articles inside.

Comment: I think Workbench would be a choice. However it is based on taxonomy when grouping articles into issues which is not a always good idea. I was looking for a node reference aproach.